# How to calculate the distance in a specified direction of a point from a (complex) BooleanRegion?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

As an example (but the size of the rectangles and the position of the point are within predetermined random ranges):

```
rect1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 5}];
rect2 = Rectangle[{11, 0}, {20, 20}];
region = RegionUnion[rect1, rect2];
p = Point[{0,12}]
```

I would like to calculate the distance roughly as follows:
`RegionDistance[region, {10, 12}]` BUT in the right direction and not in the bottom direction.

Comment: The line from point {0,12} in direction {10,12}  does not cut "region"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rect1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 5}];
rect2 = Rectangle[{11, 0}, {20, 20}];
region = RegionUnion[rect1, rect2];
pt = {0, 12};
dir = {1, 0};
dist = RegionDistance[RegionIntersection[HalfLine[pt, dir], region]]@pt
Graphics[{DiscretizeRegion@region, {Blue, AbsolutePointSize[8], 
   Point[pt]}, Red, Arrow[{pt, pt + dist*Normalize@dir}]}]
```

> `11`.